# Visual Studio is loading the wrong source file for debugging

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

This one is really weird. I have an application I'm trying to debug. For some reason when an error occurs it breaks in to the debugger but loads the wrong file. It's looking at a file in a completely separate project within my solution. Any ideas what's going on?

Comment: Are any of the assemblies in GAC?

Comment: Did you set the project you want to debug as the default (startup) project? It would be in bold.

Comment: Is your code on your machine the latest from Source Control

Comment: No assemblies in GAC. Yes it's the startup project. Yes it's the latest from source control.

Comment: Have you done a Build/Clean? And have you made sure you are debugging it in the proper location (IIS or VS Web Server)?

Comment: Try Right-Clicking on the project, selecting Debug->Start New Instance

Comment: Does it happen with all errors or one particular one?

Comment: You could try recreating the project.

Comment: @Micah I had this issue once where i had two instance of VS open I modified in first one but was accidentally debugging with second one

Comment: @micah Are the two projects exes or dlls?